# prevent dupplicate submitted by ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using ajax to create list of replies.

In the end of the list I added textarea form that allow user to add reply (also with ajax).

The problem is that i call to my JS in my main PHP page so when user want to submit reply the page doesn't "know" the js code. If i add the js to the ajax php file/page the code will work but then it will be duplicated many times and when user will submit form the text will be submitted many times...

In my console i see that the JS file duplicate every time i load the replies list

How can i prevent it?

Comment: Can we see your code please?

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: You need to disable the submit button after it has been pressed. You can find many examples online.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more about your structure of your files? How does your ajax PHP file look like? Why is the js code not "known" when you put it in your main PHP page It's unclear for me what exactly do you mean.

Comment: @Ben - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918915/how-to-prevent-duplicate-code-phpajax

Comment: @KARTHISRV - - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918915/how-to-prevent-duplicate-code-phpajax

Comment: @dns_nx - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918915/how-to-prevent-duplicate-code-phpajax

Answer (score 0):

Disable the submit button right after user presses it once.
 Using jQuery:

```
$("#button").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Make sure to remove `disabled` attribute **on AJAX error** so user can re-submit the form with new data.
 You can remove `disabled` attribute like this:

```
$('#button').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: but the problem is not with double submitting by the user. the issue is that the js file get loaded more than 1 time...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918915/how-to-prevent-duplicate-code-phpajax

Answer (score 0):

[improved]
if you want to not repeat data when navigation or F5 press, simply free the $_POST vars after doing whatever you want, and check if isnt set (before clean, of course) redirect you wherever you want. example:

```
/* HERE do the job with ajax response. */
     if(!isset($_post['foo'])) header('Location: wherever.php');
$_POST['foo']=NULL;
```

If you're using $_GET... don't do it, use $_POST... $_POST is your friend.

Finaly ensure that if you press F5, you don't re-send form vars by post (otherwise you will get the same). If it's happening, clear your inputs with jQuery on page load.

```
$('#inputID').val('');
```

Comment: The problem is not with double submitting by the user. the issue is that the js file get loaded more than 1 time...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918915/how-to-prevent-duplicate-code-phpajax

Comment: Even if it's happening, you must free vars to prevent it drastically.
Then, check where are you calling those JS and how did you coded it.

It's a good pratice to call a jquery function with preventdefault when onclick event on send button. then you can check wherever you want (for example if var duplicated !== 1) so, when your js makes whatever you can put this var to 1 and nothing will happen on next load, then when you press again the send button with onlcick jquery function with prevent default, you can set it to 1 and do again whatever you want).